# Add multiple values of string to string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuilder

I have a program where I am calling a method that reads an xls file and fetches the 2nd column.

```
public static String readExcel(String FileName) throws BiffException,
            IOException, java.text.ParseException, InterruptedException {

    String ss = null;
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FileName);

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;

    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

    // TO get the access to the sheet
    HSSFSheet sh = workbook.getSheet("data");

    int rowCount = sh.getLastRowNum() - sh.getFirstRowNum();
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

        Row row = sh.getRow(i);

        // Create a loop to print cell values in a row

        for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++) {
            Cell alpha = row.getCell(j);
            String Beta = formatter.formatCellValue(alpha);
            String leftRemoved = Beta.substring(0);
            String GammaRemove = leftRemoved.trim();
            dateStringList.add(GammaRemove);
            // System.out.println(dateStringList);

        }

    }
    System.out.println("The String contains" + dateStringList);
    ArrayList<String> Beta = dateStringList;
    String[] s1 = new String[256];
    for (int k = 1; k < dateStringList.size(); k++) {
        String gamma = Beta.get(k);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(gamma);
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
        System.out.println("The New String is" + sb);
        // String ss1=sb.toString();
        // System.out.println("The String SS is" + ss);
        ss = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("The String SS is" + ss);
    }
    fs.close();
    return ss;

}
```

I am trying to use stringBuilder to remove the leading space of the 2nd column string values. But I want to fetch all these stringbuilder values from this method and store them in a string array which I am not able to do as it is throwing type a mismatch error.

How can I get all the string values from this StringBuilder and store them in a string array?

Comment: If you just want to remove leading/trailing spaces, you can call the `.trim()` method on a string

Comment: Where in your code you are getting the error? If you only what to delete the first character in a String, you can use substring method (s.substring, 1);

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use StringBuilder for it. You can directly use trim() function with your string.

```
String gamma = Beta.get(k);
gamma=gamma.trim();
```

And you can then directly save them in an Array.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. :)

Comment: Welcome @shahabazahmed, if this solves your problem please accept the answer.